# Warning on running tensor flow in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, cpu

I am trying to learn tensorflow and just started with the basics. To install tensorflow I used the following command: `pip install tensorflow`

Now, when I run the basic tensorflow programs, it shows the following warning:

`Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA`

Should I be worried? Will it still give me a proper result when I go for complex programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the binaries you installed on your PC are do not have support for instruction sets such as [SSE4](http://www.cpu-world.com/Glossary/S/SSE4.1.html). This may not give optimum performance for the programs but in normal case won't affect the execution.

If you want to enable those supports, try to compile the sources with relevant flags and install it replacing the pip installed versions. Go for [installing with VirtualEnv](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv)